# Need the subtract of two glist object in c

Tags: c, glib

Assume:

g1 and g2 are a glist objects that holds the following chars (not a char**)

```
g1 = {"a", "b", "c"};

g2 = {"b", "d", "e"};
```

I need a code using c glist library that returns the subtract of the list;

```
g3 = subtract (g1, g2);
should return 
{"a", "c");

g4 = subtract (g2, g1);
should return 
{"d", "e");
```

Comment: Is this a homework?

Comment: no it isn't a home work

Comment: [Glib - Glist Example in Description](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html) may be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void glist_deep_copy_g_func(gpointer data, gpointer user_data) {
    GList** result = user_data;
    if (data) {
        *result = g_list_append(*result, strdup(data));
    }
    user_data = result;
}

GList* glist_deep_copy(GList* source) {
    GList* result = NULL;
    g_list_foreach(source, &glist_deep_copy_g_func, &result);
    return result;
}

gint glib_compare_char_ptr(gconstpointer a, gconstpointer b) {
    return strcmp(a, b);
}

GList* glist_subtract(GList* from, GList* by) {
    GList* result = NULL;

    if (from && by) {
        result = glist_deep_copy(from);
        for (GList *node_from = g_list_first(from); node_from; node_from =
                g_list_next(node_from)) {
            for (GList *node_by = g_list_first(by); node_by; node_by =
                    g_list_next(node_by)) {
                if (!strcmp(node_from->data, node_by->data)) {
                    GList* node = g_list_find_custom(result, node_from->data,
                            &glib_compare_char_ptr);
                    char* data = node->data;
                    result = g_list_remove(result, node->data);
                    free(data);
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (from) {
        return glist_deep_copy(from);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can review the implementation of [`std::set_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) and adapt it for `glist`.

There is no implementation of set difference within GLib itself.

Comment: But this is for c, not c++.

Comment: I said 'adapt', not 'copy-paste'. The idea can be seen in that code, the implementation can be rewritten in plain C and for glist structure. OP just has to keep in mind the iterator in the C++ algorithm is the same thing as a pointer to a list item in C.